# Javascript array seemingly stored as string

Tags: javascript

I am working on a turn-based game in a website, using jQuery (version 2.1.4).
I have a custom object constructor to make player objects.  This is it:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/4fe3e81dd35e33d6cba5527e451032e2.png]

As you can see, on the final line the attacks property-key has an associated value of an array.

Then I added a function to check if a certain value is in an array, which can be found here:

[image: enter link description here]

Lastly, a function to let a player choose an attack out of the list of attacks that are available to them.
To prevent errors or other unwanted behaviour, I check if the attack chosen through a prompt is in the list of attacks available to the player. In the code this looks like this:

```
if (player.attacks.contains(chosen_attack)) {
    *execute some code*
};
```

Now what I want to have happen, is that if the user inputs 'defense' rather than 'defense down', the `.contains()` function returns false and the code is not executed, instead the player is asked which attack they want to use again.
However, it returns true if the user inputs 'defense'. I then tried setting the content of a div equal to player.attacks, and as it turned out player.attacks was stored as if I had called the `.join('');` function on it; rather than it being an array, it was a string of the different values in the array bluntly put after each other.
I tried setting the content of the same div to `{typeof player.attacks}`, and it said object, which would suggest it is still an array.

Why is it that the array is stored as a string?
Or is the array parsed into a string whenever it's called?

Comment: The second method has `return true` twice. Is this really intentional?

Comment: You should add the relevant code to the question, not images.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as links to pictures.

Comment: Wiktor Zychla, it was not, I noticed as well. It should have return false. I changed that.

Comment: To debug this, you could try printing out what 'chosen_attack' is each time to ensure it is what you expect.  The code looks sound, although you should probably avoid messing with Array prototypes out of good practice.  Is there anything else interfering with the 'attacks' property on any of your player instances?  You may also want to consider making 'attacks' a 'set' instead of an array.  You can do this by having 'attacks' just be a standard object. This would remove the need for having to traverse the whole array to check if a given 'chosen_attack' is valid.

Comment: @Mahout I ended up being able to fix it through changing the array function to check for strict equality (it originally was not, I updated the code).  
Is it bad to modify prototypes? I thought it was quite convenient and I quite enjoy it. It is one of the few unique things about javascript to me. Any specific reason I should avoid it?
Nothing is altering the attacks property after creating the instances.
Using a set is indeed a good solution, thank you.